# Why column order in chart does not match column order in resultset of query?

Tags: charts, birt

I have some query, and I output the result of this query in a table and try to display it in a chart. The "Select Data" tab of the chart editing window looks like this:

[image]

All works right, except of the fact that order in the chart does not match column order in the resultset of query. I put arrows on the screenshot with this chart, with text that points to the corresponding row in table (for example, 0 row - the first row in table, 1 row - the second row in table, etc.):

[image]

It seems that `row.__rownum` values is sorted like varchar, rather than integer (for example, like `ORDER BY` works for `varchar` in mysql). How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially I found the answer: all that I needed was to click "Edit grouping and sorting" and change type in "Grouping" section from "Text" to "Numeric":

[image]

I hope it will be useful for somebody else.